# Why am I unable to build pyodide?

Tags: makefile, chmod, pyodide

I find myself attempting to build [pyodide from sources](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/development/building-from-sources.html) on a linux machine. However an attempt to run the make command gives me the following `permission denied` error.

```
savakar@Qulal:/media/savakar/PROJECTS/pyodide$ make
./tools/dependency-check.sh
/bin/bash: line 1: ./tools/dependency-check.sh: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:201: check] Error 126
```

I have installed the build dependencies from the Dockerfile.
It appears to be a permissions issue, however I have attempted to give read,write and execution permissions to the directory via the command

```
chmod 777 -R /media/savakar/PROJECTS/pyodide/
chmod +rwx -R pyodide/
chmod +rwx -R ./tools
```

amongst other attempts at giving execute permission to the files.

Comment: It's not the directory, it's the script.  That's clear from the error message: `./tools/dependency-check.sh: Permission denied` so the permissions problem is on the file `./tools/dependency-check.sh`.  You need to make this file executable: `chmod +x ./tools/dependency-check.sh`.  I have no idea why it's not already executable.  Probably you should report this to the project.

Comment: Running this command is **very** dangerous: `chmod 777 -R /media/savakar/PROJECTS/pyodide/`

Comment: I recommend using the Docker container to build Pyodide instead of trying to install the tools locally.

Comment: @johnHanley would it be okay if you could explain a little more on how to use Docker to build pyodide, as I find the information on the building from sources a little difficult to follow.

Comment: It would be easier if you explain what problem you have running the Docker container to build Pyodide.